# Is there any plugin for WikiEditor I could implement in my own page/ site

Tags: mediawiki, wikimedia

My client wants an Editor same as WikiEditor with all its functionalities in his website (framework almost near to codeigniter). I've seen the editor "WikiEditor" by implementing MediaWiki but I couldn't get it seperately into my page. Hope anyones got some answer out there.

Thanks and Regards,
Rajesh Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want HTML output, you might have luck with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).
If by "an Editor same as WikiEditor with all its functionalities" mean that you want wikitext output, then you probably have to look in the MediaWiki source.